# How to process PHP code in a text string, to prevent it from being seen as text?

Tags: php, string, text, escaping

I'm using the Redactor editor in a custom built CMS. Redactor has an option, `phpTags`, which when set to `true` allows PHP code to be entered and saved as part of the content.

The issue is that this PHP code is being seen as text, not PHP code, and is being escaped rather than being processed.

For example, if I enter this in the editor:

`<?php echo date('Y'); ?>`

Instead of the year being displayed, the code is commented out in the page's markup, like so:

`<!--?php echo date('Y'); ?-->`

How can I prevent this from happening? To make sure the PHP code is processed/interpreted as such by the server?

I should probably mention that there are a lot of people using this CMS, so there's no way to know what PHP code may be added in advance.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you have to enable support for phpTags before you use it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I first tried str_replace to replace `<!--?php` with `<?php`, and likewise with the closing PHP tag. This didn't result in any change to what was displayed not he webpage. I then viewed the database directly, and the code there is as it should be. The data is retrieve from the db and passed to a function that uses `echo` to display it on the page, so the `echo`ed text includes the correctly formatted PHP code. It appears the browser is interpreting the PHP as text, and commenting it out.

Comment: @BrianV Yes, you do, and I have. With the `phpTags` option set to `false` PHP tags are stripped from the content completely, and never saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I took the content I was previously just displaying via `echo`, and saved it to a temporary file.

Then I turned on output buffering, included that temporary file in the PHP script, and grabbed its contents via `ob_get_contents()`.

This allowed me to display the content with all the PHP within having been parsed. Here's the code for reference:

```
// Create path to temporary file
$tmpPath = '/temp.php';

// Set file variable to null for error checking
$tmpFile = NULL;

// Try creating the temporary file
if ( $tmpFile = fopen($tmpPath, 'w') ) {
   if ( fwrite($tmpFile, $postContent) === FALSE ) {
      // Do something if the file can't be written to
   } else {
      // Close file
      fclose($tmpFile);
   }
}

// Start output buffereing
ob_start();

// Include the temporary file created above
include $tmpPath;

// Save buffered contents to a variable
$content = ob_get_contents();

// End output buffering
ob_end_clean();

// Display content
echo $content;
```

I appreciate the various comments to my question, as it helped prod me in the right direction to getting this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
<!-- <?php echo date('Y') ?> -->
```

You can't change PHP's opening/closing tags like you are, not without a recompile of PHP. If you want to hide php's output, then surround the entire php code block with html comment tags.

PHP won't care about the html comments. It couldn't care at all what it's embedded in. You could stuff a PHP code block into the middle of a .jpg file and it'd still execute, as long as the webserver's configured to run .jpg files through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: The PHP code is correct (that is, not being commented out) when stored in the database. It is only when echoed onto the page that (I assume) the browser sees the PHP code in the text string and comments it out. I'm guessing here the PHP code is not being treated and interpreted as code at all, hence why the browser comments it out. My goal is to prevent it from being commented out, so the server processes it as PHP code rather than formatted text.